# jQuery not working in IE, works in other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, load

Currently coding a mates portfolio and not to my surprise the code isn't loading in IE!

I'm coding it using standard AJAX, here's the relevant jQuery:

```
//ajax shtuff

$(window).load(function() {

    // Ajax Cache!
    $.ajaxSetup ({  
        cache: false  
    });

    var $loadW = '<div id="whiteLoader" />';
    var $loadurl = $('.current').attr('href');

    // Initial Page Load
    $('#con').prepend($loadW);
    $('#main').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).load($loadurl + ' .page', function() {
            $(this).parent().find('#whiteLoader').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                $(this).parent().find('#main').fadeIn('slow').css({background: 'red'});
                $(this).remove();
            });
        });
    });

    $('nav ul li a').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function(e) {

            var $loadW = '<div id="whiteLoader" />';
            var $loadurl = $(this).attr('href');

            // Prevent default hotlink
            e.preventDefault();

            // Add the current state
            $('*').removeClass('current');
            $(this).addClass('current');

            // Load the Page
            $('#main').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                $('#con').prepend($loadW);
                $('#main').load($loadurl + ' #main', function() {
                    $('#whiteLoader').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                        $('#main').fadeIn('slow');
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                });
            });

        });
    });

});
```

Literally have no idea why this doesnt work lol, here's a link to the live page (I've put the background as red just to show you the area.)

Also the reason the initial page is using the 'this' method is because I was testing it both ways.

http://212.7.200.35/~tfbox/zee/

Comment: Do you have several elements with ID `#main`?

Comment: @Felix - That was the first thing I thought would be the issue, so I changed that, still no luck. If you notice on page load it loads the relevant URL + the class 'page'

Comment: @tfbox: This is not the problem, but you can write `$('#main').fadeIn()` instead of `$(this).parent().find('#main').fadeIn()`

Comment: @Felix - Yes I know, Read the bottom of the post thats how I originally had it, but I tried that as an alternative method.

Comment: another idea: i once had a problem using the new HTML5 nav tag with IE. is that what you have here? $('nav ul li a'). try a div and see if that works

Comment: @dustmason - that wont change anything since the event is already being fired. It's working. It seems as though it loads the Div from the page into the div but not the inner contents of the div from the page. Really weird!

Comment: @DustMason - Post an answer about the use of HTML5 Tag Section and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often IE has trouble styling / selecting any of the new HTML5 elements such as `section` and `nav`. Try using something like [this](http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-shiv/) or simply using a div

Answer (score 3):

have you tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Stuff to do as soon as the DOM is ready;
});
```

instead of window.load?

Comment: window.load and document.ready are completely different things.  Onload happens before DomContentReady, it is a more than valid suggestion.